# Как настроить node.js и Spring Boot на одном порте localhost?

Tags: node.js, spring, localhost, virtual-hosts

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией.
Запустил на ПК сервер node.js на порт 8080 чтобы работать с бэк частью приложения.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app = express()

const apiKey = '*****************';

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {weather: null, error: null});
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  let city = req.body.city;
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`

  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    if(err){
      res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
    } else {
      let weather = JSON.parse(body)
      if(weather.main == undefined){
        res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
      } else {
        let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees in ${weather.name}!`;
        res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, error: null});
      }
    }
  });
})

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!')
})
```

Бэк написан на Spring Boot.

Когда запускаю Spring Boot то получаю ошибку

```
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

как можно решить эту проблему чтобы разрабатывать и фронт и бек на одной машине?

Comment: Два приложения на одном порту в любом случае работать не будут. Нужно делать прокси, которая будет перенаправлять запросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте порт либо для сервера node, либо для spring boot приложения

Для spring boot приложения меняется в application.yml (application.properties) добавлением следующей настройки:

```
server:
  port: 8236
```

Не забудьте после изменения порта одного из приложений поменять порт в настройках второго.

Если обязательно нужно чтобы оба приложения работали на порте 8080, то заверните каждый из них в Docker, создайте для каждого из контейнеров свою сеть и запускайте каждый в своей сети и также понадобится настройка общения между сетями контейнеров (но это сложный путь - проще поменяйте порт у одного из приложений).